# Pass Session variable to the ajax called PHP script

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

While using the sessions in my PHP script I wanted to pass the session variable to the PHP called script. But the session variables are not being called as the session_start() function could not be used after the HTML code. I am using the simple Javascript AJAX. Please provide me the path.

Comment: I don't understand. Where is your script failing? What do you currently have?

Comment: so you can't access sessions-vars in the phpscript you call with your ajax?

Comment: you may `echo` your php session variable inside JavaScript

Comment: @Mohammer yeah but i found the alternative by passing session id and storing the needful details in database and on session_destroy removing the entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you need is the following:

in your php-script you open/request with ajax, you have to add in the first line:

```
session_start(session_id());
```

This way, you have access to the variables you stored in your session where you called the request with ajax

Comment: Thanx I just passed this session id with the link passed by AJAX.