# session id changing on ajax call to file in subfolder

Tags: php

I am calling an ajax file in my top directory ("/filename.php")

The ajax file is located in a sub directory ("/uploads/filename.php")

When I call the `start_session()` function and then echo the session id at the top of each page, the session id is different on the file in the top directory than the session id on the file in the sub directory.

I need access to the session variables created in the top directory from the sub directory. What do I have to do to accomplish this?

Comment: Try to removing the `start_session()` from the second page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124560/pass-session-variable-to-the-ajax-called-php-script/10124925#10124925

Comment: @Mohammer That doesn't do anything. I get a different session still

Comment: @rcdmk Doing that causes there not to be a session at all. I don't know why you'd think that would fix my problem.

Comment: Do you removed only from the second one? The first page still needs it.

Comment: Yes I removed it.. I kept it on the first page. There was no session data available on the second because there was no session started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how I can do this, but I can pass the session variables for a username and password via ajax, check them with the database, and then get information based on that

Answer (score 0):

The session ID should be the same, regardless of what directory your script is in (unless server-side config defines otherwise). You are not naming your session are you? If not, you can try naming the session example:

file.php

```
session_name("example");
session_start();
echo session_id();
```

other/file.php

```
session_name("example");
session_start();
echo session_id();
```